# When to use tf.resource and tf.variant?

Tags: tensorflow

TensorFlow DType has tf.resource and tf.variant with pretty vague description. Can someone please explain to me what those two types are for? It'd be great if there are examples. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

These are internal types for tracking special tensor objects such as variables and datasets:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaRO0AV6Tto